# Update only First Occurence of element in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to update/touch only the first occurrence of an element in HTML using external CSS. For example:

```html
<section>
  <article>
      <h2>20 CSS Best Practices</h2> 
   <p>
    <ul>
     <li>ABC</li>
     <li>XYZ</li>
     </ul>
    </p>
  </article>

  <article>
   <h2>CSS References</h2>
   <p>
    <ul>
     <li>ABC</li>
     <li>XYZ</li> 
    </ul>
    </p>
  </article>
  
  <article>
   <h2>Additional References</h2>
   <p>
    <ul>
     <li>ABC</li>
     <li>XYZ</li>
    </ul>
    </p>
  </article>
 </section>
```

In the above code, I want to touch only the first occurrence of `<h2>` only in the first `article`, not in all the `articles`.

But using first-of-type is updating all the `<h2>` across all the  . I know there is a way to update it through class or ID attribute, but I don't want to do it that way. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: `section > article:first-child > h2{ }`

Comment: `section :first-child :first-child { ... }`

Comment: Check updated answer to style only the `h2` tag in first `article` tag

Answer (score 2):

Use `nth-of-type` to get the same

Add below css part

```
section article:nth-of-type(1) h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
section article:nth-of-type(1) h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <h2>20 CSS Best Practices</h2>
    <p>
      <ul>
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>XYZ</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>CSS References</h2>
    <p>
      <ul>
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>XYZ</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Additional References</h2>
    <p>
      <ul>
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>XYZ</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </article>
</section>
```

You can also use `first-of-type` to get it

```css
section article:first-of-type h2{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <h2>20 CSS Best Practices</h2>
    <p>
      <ul>
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>XYZ</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>CSS References</h2>
    <p>
      <ul>
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>XYZ</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Additional References</h2>
    <p>
      <ul>
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>XYZ</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </article>
</section>
```

`first-child` use as well

```css
section article:first-child h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <h2>20 CSS Best Practices</h2>
    <p>
      <ul>
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>XYZ</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>CSS References</h2>
    <p>
      <ul>
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>XYZ</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Additional References</h2>
    <p>
      <ul>
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>XYZ</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: `:nth-of-type(1)` is the overcomplicated way of saying `:first-of-type`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the multiple solutions. It is what I desired. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Please upvote /accept answer so it will be helpful to other community members